# Dropdown menu fails in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

My jquery dropdown menu is fails in IE7 or IE8 Compatibility view.

I use this jquery for the dropdown menu in the below link:

```
var timeout    = 1000;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{  jsddm_canceltimer();
   jsddm_close();
   ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');}

function jsddm_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function jsddm_timer()
{  closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{  $('.menu ul > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)
   $('.menu').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer)});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
```

http://www.urbanlifefeed.com/cruise_ulf/

And this is the css:

```
div.menu { height:49px;}
div.menu ul {
    /*width:886px;
    margin:0 7px;*/
    width:921px;
    margin:0;
    background:url(images/nav_bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
    float:left;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
div.menu ul li {
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:21px;
    line-height:49px;
    padding:0 12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    float:left;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    position:relative;
}
div.menu ul li ul
    {
    position:absolute;
    top:49px;
    left:0;
    width:280px;
    border:0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    background:url(images/sub_nav_bg.png) repeat 0 0;
    z-index:999999 !important;
    visibility:hidden;
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    }
div.menu ul li ul li:hover {background:url(images/sub_nav_bg.png) repeat 0 0;}
div.menu ul li ul li
    {
    border:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #f4c726;
    width:256px;;
    float:left;
    }
div.menu ul li ul li a
    { color:#f4c726; text-transform:capitalize;}
div.menu ul li:hover{
    background:url(images/nav_roll_bg.png) repeat-x center 0;
}
div.menu ul li a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    height:49px;
    width:100%;
}
div.menu ul li a:hover{
    color:#fbf0cc;
    }
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to explain **how** you code fails. What are you expecting to happen and what happens instead? Do you get any errors? Describe the problem you have, if you want somebody to solve it.

Comment: use and understand clearfix http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html replace `content: ".";` with `content: "\00A0";` which will get replace the dot with a white space...

Comment: IE7 or IE8 Compatibility view. the the menu is going to the behind the banner

Comment: Please see http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#stack

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the menu is sitting behind the slider container. You could use the [z-index attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to ensure that the menu block always appears above the slider block. For example, the div that holds the slider you can set a z-index of 1, and then set the menu  a z-index of 2 or above.

Comment: z index of the slider is 1 for that menu its z-index: 999999 !important;

Comment: When using `z-index`, don't forget that the element's `position` CSS attribute needs to be explicitly set. Otherwise, `z-index` will have no affect.